# Probability Matrix with transaction costs

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For example, say for example you have a matrix with the following states

$
\begin{matrix}
 & 1 &2  &3 &4\\ 
 1& a &b& c&d \\ 
 2& e &f &g&h\\ 
 3& i & j & k &l\\
4&0&0&0&1
\end{matrix}
$

with a transition cost matrix of

$
\begin{matrix}
 & 1 &2  &3 &4\\ 
 1& o &p& q&r \\ 
 2& s &t &u&v\\ 
 3& w & x & y &z\\
4&0&0&0&0
\end{matrix}
$

for example, going to state 3 from state 1 would cost $ q $

Say that you start at 1 and you continue until you reach the absorbing state of 4, what would be the expected cost? What kind of problem is this named?

Comment: Source of the exercise?

Comment: expected cumulative reward until absorption

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Answer (score 1):

First we need to rewrite the cost and transition matrices as follows:

$$T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
&&&0\\
&A&&\vdots\\
&&&0\\
\hline
&v^T&&1
\end{array}\right)~~~~,~~~~C=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
&&&0\\
&B&&\vdots\\
&&&0\\
\hline
&w^T&&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Here $T,C$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $A,B$ are $(n-1)\times (n-1).$ Furthermore, the entries of the vectors $v,w$ are determined by the requirement that the sum of transition probabilities is $1$. Also denote the initial state by $S_0^T=(\mathbf{s}_0,a_0)=(1,0,0,0)$.

First we can compute the probability of absorption at each step. It turns out that we can write

$$(s_N)_i=A^N(s_0)_i ~~,~~ i=1,...,n-1$$

while the absorption probability is

$$(s_N)_n=v^T(1+A+...+A^{n-1})s_0$$

Now, we can't just use the above calculation to infer the expected value of the cost, since every realization of the Markov chain has a different cost. We write out the first few terms for absorption at steps 1, 2 and 3 by looking, say, at the tree branches of the process:

$$\mathbb{E}[C]=\sum_i v_iw_i{s_{0i}}+\sum_{ij}v_iw_iA_{ij}B_{ij}s_{0j}+\sum_{ijk}v_iw_iA_{ij}B_{ij}A_{jk}B_{jk}s_{0k}+...$$

However, we get lucky because the expectation value can be written succinctly with the help of the component by component product $(A\times B)_{ij}:=A_{ij}B_{ij}$ as

$$\mathbb{E}[C]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (v\times w)^T(A\times B)^{n-1}s_0=(v\times w)^T(1-A\times B)^{-1}s_0$$

The last expression can be computed efficiently for any matrices $A,B$ by using the Jordan decomposition, or using the eigenvalue decomposition, if the inverse of $(1-A\times B)$ exists.